# the sum of elements of all possible subset $B$ is

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,\cdots \cdots ,22\}$ and $B$ is a subset of $A$ having exactly $11$ elements.
>
> Then the sum of elements of all possible subset $B$ is

$\bf{Attempt}$ Number of subset of $A$ having excatly $11$ elements is $\displaystyle \binom{22}{11}$

Now how can i find sum of elements of all subset of $B$, could some help me , thanks

Comment: Symmetry. Every element occurs as frequently as it doesn't. So the average element is 11.5. And there are 11 times 22 choose 11 emements. So the sum is 11.5 times 11 timed 22 choose 11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For each 11-element subset $B$ of $A$, its complement $A\setminus B$ also is an 11-element subset.  The elements of those two subsets sum up to $S = 22\times23/2 = 253$.  As there are $\binom{22}{11}$ 11-element subsets, we have an overall total of  $S\times\binom{22}{11} = 178474296$ (which counts each such subset exactly twice, once as a subset in its own right, and once as a complement) giving an answer of $178474296/2 = 89237148$.

[This is equivalent to the answer noted in a comment, which I saw after answering.]

Answer (score 4):

The generating function for subsets of $N_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ weighted by sums is

$$ \sum_{S \subseteq N_n} x^{\#S}q^{\operatorname{sum}(S)} = (1 + qx)(1 + q^2x)\cdots(1 + q^{n}x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n q^{k(k+1)/2} \begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}_q x^k. $$

So if we set $n = 22$ and sum over subsets of $N_{22}$ with $11$ elements, we get

$$ \sum_{B} q^{\operatorname{sum}(B)} = q^{66}\begin{bmatrix} 22 \\ 11 \end{bmatrix}_q. $$

Now differentiate with respect to $q$ to get

$$ \sum_{B} \operatorname{sum}(B)q^{\operatorname{sum}(B) - 1} = \frac{d}{dq} \left( q^{66}\begin{bmatrix} 22 \\ 11 \end{bmatrix}_q \right). $$

Finally set $q = 1$ to obtain

$$ \sum_{B} \operatorname{sum}(B) = 89237148. $$

Where the last quantity was computed using Mathematica:

```
D[q^66 QBinomial[22,11,q]//FunctionExpand, q] /. q -> 1
```

You can also give this same command to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bq%5E66+QBinomial%5B22,11,q%5D%2F%2FFunctionExpand,+q%5D+%2F.+q+-%3E+1).